# How to move this ColorPicker from iPhone to a portion of iPad scene?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, storyboard

I found a ColorPicker ([ILColorPicker](https://github.com/jawngee/ILColorPicker)) that takes the whole screen on an iPhone.  I want to use it in my iPad app (XCode4 using StoryBoards)... it's asking me to "In your view controller's XIB, add a UIView and then set it's class to ILColorPickerView ".  I don't want to use the entire scene, just a small part of it... is there another way I can accomplish this? (using Layers, frames, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could programmatically [create a popover](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial) (UIPopoverViewController), and put the color picker as the view for your popover.

Comment: That would work as a last resort... is there no way to put it on a scene?  I have about 6 or more items that the user wants to be able to change the color on...