# Why won't this code allocate a subView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

This is my code where I'm trying to create a subView... I'm using XCode4 with StoryBoards.  The app is crashing on the 2nd line where it is allocating subView with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  vFrame has valid content.  What is wrong with this?  (I'm using XCode4 with Storyboards, btw).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect vFrame = CGRectMake(60,100,200,200);
    subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:vFrame];
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview: subView];
}
```

UPDATE:  definition for subView:

```
@interface PreferencesViewController : UIViewController  {

    UIView *subView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIView *subView;

@end
```

Comment: What is subView? Is it defined somewhere?

Comment: I created a test project with a storyboard (Xcode 4.2, SDK 5.0) and pasted in your code: no problem.  Try putting a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions, or catching the exception, and seeing what the stack symbols look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the UIViewController was farkled...don't know how, but once it was replaced, it worked like a champ!  Thank you all for your responses...

Answer (score 1):

That really should work. Was your view controller (PreferencesViewController) properly alloc'd and init'd? Did you @synthesize your subview?

Although it shouldn't matter, you could try using floats for the CGRect (add a .0 to the end of each).

Comment: Hi Adam... yes, subView was @synthesiz'ed... floats made no difference...what about it being XCode4 with storyboards?  And I know it's getting to the PreferencesViewController because that's where the code resides... I wonder if it's a XCode4 bug?

Comment: ADam... go to yesterdays Q(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015985/how-to-move-this-colorpicker-from-iphone-to-a-portion-of-ipad-scene): and see my last comment...

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your sub view instantiation code to the method viewWillAppear of your main view. This guarantees everything has been initialized.